Geometry nodes: objects become too small when I "reset children"
I was trying to add sprinkles to a donut in geometry nodes but when I clicked "reset children", the sprinkles became really small. does anyone know why that happened and how I can fix it?


Apply scale (Ctrl+a) -- original sprinkles, icing and donut

I tried to scale the original sprinkles but it didn't work. thanks for the answer though.

I didn't say "scale" (s), I said "apply scale" (ctrl+a)

oh, thank you so much, it actually worked! (I'm new to blender so I'm still trying to figure out how everything works)

The discord channel suggested in the tutorial has lots of people facing the same issues every hour, it's a good place to go ask these donut questions.

ok, thanks again for your help
